# Upgraded to VS2008, but winform controls still VS2003 style

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2003

I've upgraded to Visual Studio 2008 and .net 3.5. I've migrated an application that was running on .net 1.1, and all of my controls still have the 1.1 look and feel. In the designer, the look/style of the controls has updated, but during runtime, it's not.

How do I force the switch?

Comment: You must have forgotten to change something that tells where the components will get their feel and look from

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call [`Application.EnableVisualStyles()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.enablevisualstyles.aspx) at the beginning of `Main()`.